# Shell Script to create folders and move files to new folders

Tags: bash, shell, freebsd

I have a FreeNAS 9.3 installation set up and have 5 network cameras capturing pictures to a share on the NAS. I need a script that I can run as a cron job on a weekly basis that moves the files into dated folders so that it is much easier to navigate to a specific date to monitor the cameras.

The folder structure looks like this:

The Root folder is

```
/mnt/Data/Camera2
```

and within this folder, I have my 5 cameras

```
/mnt/Data/Camera2/CHF
/mnt/Data/Camera2/CHR
/mnt/Data/Camera2/GCMR
/mnt/Data/Camera2/GCMF
/mnt/Data/Camera2/GCMS
```

Within each of these camera folders, the network camera automatically creates folders such as Snapshot_time and Record_alarm

I have archive folders in

```
/mnt/Data/Camera2/Archive/CHF
/mnt/Data/Camera2/Archive/CHR
/mnt/Data/Camera2/Archive/GCMR
/mnt/Data/Camera2/Archive/GCMF
/mnt/Data/Camera2/Archive/GCMS
```

What I need the script to do is when ran,
Make dirs in each of the above archive folders with the current date, ie. WB_21-08-2015

Once these dirs are created, I then need to move the contents of the above camera folders into the respective archive folders.

I have asked on the FreeNAS forums and not had much help so far, but I do have the following script. When I run it, I get all sorts of errors...

```
#!/bin/bash
ROOT_DIR="/mnt/Data/Camera2"
BACKUP_DIRS="$ROOT_DIR/Archive/GCMF $ROOT_DIR/Archive/GCMR $ROOT_DIR/Archive/GCMS $ROOT_DIR/Archive/CHF $ROOT_DIR/Archive/CHR"
DATE=$(date +%d-%m-%Y)
DATE_DIR="WB_$(date +%d-%m-%Y)"
LOG_DIR="$ROOT_DIR/Logs/WB_$(date +%d-%m-%Y)"
LOG_FILE="$LOG_DIR/${DATE}.txt"

/bin/mkdir -p $LOG_DIR

/bin/echo "Weekly DDL camera backup:" > $LOG_FILE
/bin/echo "" >> $LOG_FILE

for FOLDER in $BACKUP_DIRS; do mkdir "${FOLDER}/${DATE_DIR}" >> $LOG_FILE

mv -f -b $ROOT_DIR/GCMF/Snapshot_time $ROOT_DIR/Archive/GCMF/${DATE_DIR}
mv -f -b $ROOT_DIR/GCMR/Snapshot_time $ROOT_DIR/Archive/GCMR/${DATE_DIR}
mv -f -b $ROOT_DIR/GCMS/Snapshot_time $ROOT_DIR/Archive/GCMS/${DATE_DIR}
mv -f -b $ROOT_DIR/CHF/Snapshot_time $ROOT_DIR/Archive/CHF/${DATE_DIR}
mv -f -b $ROOT_DIR/CHR/Snapshot_time $ROOT_DIR/Archive/CHR/${DATE_DIR}
done
```

Please help!

EDIT:
After running the revised script by @Ecnarfi I get the following errors:

```
[root@DaffyDuck] /mnt/Data/Camera2/Scripts# /bin/bash -ex Final.sh
+ ROOT_DIR=/mnt/Data/Camera2
+ BACKUP_DIR=/mnt/Data/Camera2/Archive
+ CAMERAS='GCMF GCMR GCMS CHF CHR'
++ date +%d-%m-%Y
+ DATE=21-08-2015
++ date +%d-%m-%Y
+ DATE_DIR=WB_21-08-2015
++ date +%d-%m-%Y
+ LOG_DIR=/mnt/Data/Camera2/Logs/WB_21-08-2015
+ LOG_FILE=/mnt/Data/Camera2/Logs/WB_21-08-2015/21-08-2015.txt
+ /bin/mkdir -p /mnt/Data/Camera2/Logs/WB_21-08-2015
+ /bin/echo 'Weekly DDL camera backup:'
+ /bin/echo ''
+ for FOLDER in '${CAMERAS}'
+ mkdir /mnt/Data/Camera2/Archive/GCMF/WB_21-08-2015
+ mv -f -b /mnt/Data/Camera2/GCMF/Snapshot_time /mnt/Data/Camera2/Archive/GCMF/WB_21-08-2015
mv: illegal option -- b
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-hv] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: run your script with `bash -ex ` to show instruction and stop on first error

Comment: What's with the explicit paths? Fix your `PATH` once and let the shell find the commands. Hard-coding the command paths can only lead to problems (though those too would be obscure and rare).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop is creating an archive folder for one of the cameras and then attempting to move **all** the camera folders into it, it then tries to do the same for each of the other camera folders but as the folders have already been moved it fails.

I've amended your code and this is working for me.

```
#!/bin/bash

ROOT_DIR="/mnt/Data/Camera2"
BACKUP_DIR="${ROOT_DIR}/Archive"
CAMERAS="GCMF GCMR GCMS CHF CHR"
DATE=$(date +%d-%m-%Y)
DATE_DIR="WB_$(date +%d-%m-%Y)"
LOG_DIR="${ROOT_DIR}/Logs/WB_$(date +%d-%m-%Y)"
LOG_FILE="${LOG_DIR}/${DATE}.txt"

/bin/mkdir -p ${LOG_DIR}

/bin/echo "Weekly DDL camera backup:" > ${LOG_FILE}
/bin/echo "" >> ${LOG_FILE}

for FOLDER in ${CAMERAS}
do
   mkdir ${BACKUP_DIR}/${FOLDER}/${DATE_DIR} >> $LOG_FILE

   mv -f -b ${ROOT_DIR}/${FOLDER}/Snapshot_time ${BACKUP_DIR}/${FOLDER}/${DATE_DIR}

done
```

Comment: Thanks very much, it looks good so far however I am getting the error: `[Camera2@DaffyDuck] /mnt/Data/Camera2/Scripts% /bin/bash -ex Final.sh             + $'\r'
Final.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found`

Comment: Couldn't find how to install dos2unix or unix2dos on FreeBSD so I just opened up the editor at the ssh shell, using vi Final.sh This is what I got after taking out all the ^M from the file: [please see my edit on original post]

Comment: Looks like your version of mv doesn't support the -b option.  I guess you can either update to a version that supports it (if there is one for FreeBSD) or remove that option from the mv command if you don't need it.

Comment: Great!! removing the -b option worked!! Although, in the log fine it generated, all I have is "Weekly DDL camera backup:". How do I get the rest of the output to display in there?

Comment: EDIT: Actually after moving the Snapshot_time folders, the cameras stop recording as they dont have the ability to recreate that folder, only when you run through the setup again (junk I know)..
How do I get the script to only move the contents of the Snapshot_time folders?

Comment: If your version of mkdir supports -v then add that to the command, that should give some output to add to the log file.

In the mv command, change Snapshot_time to Snapshot_time/* to move the contents rather than the folder itself.

Comment: Now getting this weird error after having it for a few days in operation:
/mnt/Data/Camera2/Scripts/Daily-Move.sh: line 20: /bin/mv: Argument list too long